What are reasonable counter objections to the argument that materialism is incoherent because it conceptually separates Being and Mentality?
Appreciate the time. This is my first post.
I have looked at various resources and I've found that there's an aspect inherent to materialism/physicalism that gets overlooked and that I find central. And that, in general terms, is that all materialists/physicalists construct a schema, conceptually appeal to essences(even if they name it differently), argue for the position, etc... In short, they use mental categories, methods, products, to even BEGIN to define their position and make an inquiry line. This to me is obviously projecting mentality unto Being(the fundamental ontological substance) and that implies ontologizing mentality, which is contrary to the project of materialism. This is an especially pointed issue for materialists who claim mentality is a posterior, emergent movement of matter.
I came up with a syllogism that hopefully makes it clearer. Am I missing something or making an awfully big mistake? I haven't found in contemporary resources(like the SEP and so on) this even being addressed, only in older thought and usually by idealists. Here's the argument:

Realism distinguishes Being from Mentality(mind-independent). Usually making Mentality as a posterior development(emergentism).
1.1. Materialism, a form of Realism, identifies Being with Matter.

Idealism either posits Mentality as primordial and Being as secondary(Berkeley), or identifies Being with Mentality(German Idealism).

Any ontology that conceptually separates Being from Mentality implies an ontological/conceptual distinction between them.
3.1. Rationality and intelligence are intrinsic to Mentality.
3.2. The ontological disjunction between Being and Mentality entails that there is an ontological inclusive disjunction between Being and Rationality

An ontological disjunction between Being and Rationality entails making Being inherently irrational and unintelligible.
Positing Being as irrational and unintelligible implies:
4.1. Being is not apprehensible through Mentality.
4.2. Being is not modelable by the mind.
4.3. Being is not rationally modelable.

An inherently un-modelable Being cannot coherently be identified as "Matter" or "Being," as both are conceptual models.

The implications in (4) and (5) engender an epistemic and ontological absurdity:
6.1. The possibility of knowledge is undermined.
6.2. The legitimacy of discourse about reality is undermined.
6.3. The coherence of the concept of reality itself is undermined.

Therefore, ontologies that distinguish Being from Mentality, such as Realism and Materialism, are self-undermining and lead to insurmountable absurdities.



Thank you for your question. I've just edited to 'effectuate' the line break intentions in your question.

Thanks, Rushi! Appreciate it

You may rethink on monism see

If you mean that materialism/physicalism are not really monist(that is, there is an internal contradiction between the claim of monism and the conceptual reality of its monism), I would agree. But I am trying to approach this as neutrally as possible so to not get into a host of other issues with the materialist position

To counter it's equivalent to counter the possibility of philosophical-zombie whose possibility is made possible via an armchair two dimensionalism argument of intensional sense theory in philosophy of language, not unlike countering via physicalist emergent epiphenomenalism or property dualism in philosophy of mind...

Not quite sure what you mean here. Are you saying that a counter to physicalism can only be done via armchair philosophy(I suppose this is taken to be a bad thing)? I am not sure I understand the comment or what it aims to do, so I'm not sure how to address it.

Hi there. I've pointed to a similar idea here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101135/eliminative-materialism-eliminates-itself-a-familiar-idea

In short, (monistic) materialism doesn't separate being and mentality.
Dualism makes such a separation. The emergence you have in mind (which would be separate) sounds like emergent materialism (strong emergence) or epiphenomenalism. Even under those views, your argument would be flawed.
But emergence ("weak emergence") under reductive materialism doesn't propose that what emerges exists separately. Rather, this emergence or reduction is a function and a part of the underlying processes, much like we might see patterns in snowflakes emerge based on interactions of fundamental particles or forces, or see patterns emerge in traffic. That's not to say there's an entirely new mode of being for those patterns that are separate from the fundamental particles or the cars. This type of emergence or reduction is in line with how every field of science works: we see something happening, and we find that it reduces to / results from interactions of some more fundamental particles or forces.
To more specifically focus on your argument:

I wouldn't accept materialism as separating being from mentality (as above).

The idea that rationality and intelligence are intrinsic to mentality would probably be a sticking point for epiphenomenalists, who might argue that rationality and intelligence are either illusion or exist as a result of brain function, separate from mentality.
If one considers it illusionary, one might also reject the possibility of knowledge and/or the coherence of concepts. So they may accept your conclusions as true by default, even though you consider those conclusions to be "absurd".
Although I don't consider epiphenomenalism to be reasonable, because it's proposing a separate mode of being that I don't have good reason to accept, and it seems to create more problems than it solves (which I'd say holds for pretty much every dualist and idealist view, although the specific problems with each may vary).



If you say materialism is drawing a "conceptual distinction" between matter and mind on an ontological level, and that this is not a "separation":
I'm not sure I'd accept that either (although I may accept there's a weak distinction between mind and non-mind matter).
Ontology is human categorisation separate from the underlying reality that it's trying to categorise. So I would, in principle, only accept an argument built on top of ontology if it can strongly be linked back to the underlying reality (or it needs to be strongly grounded in the underlying reality from the start, and throughout the argument). That is, broadly speaking, you'd need to break down any given category and argue that the criteria we used to create said category in the underlying reality necessitates whatever you're trying to say about that category.
Getting back to your argument:

Broadly speaking, you're trying to talk about emergent things distinct from the parts they emerge from, and then draw conclusions based on this distinction. This seems to be going far into ontology without a firm grounding in underlying reality, so I don't see that one can draw conclusions about underlying reality from that.

I might grant that rationality and intelligence are intrinsic to mentality (3.1), but only weakly so (which, at best, leads to a weak deductive conclusion). I consider rationality and intelligence to be vaguely defined and that non-mind matter could potentially be said to possess those things (depending on definitions).
Under reductive materialism, our minds reduce to physical processes: firing of neurons and brain chemicals and such. One might then define rationality as these neurons being structured and weighted in such a way that, if given certain input, it will produce output according to the laws of logic and reason. Similarly, the components in a computer can be structured so as to follow those same laws, which one might say meets the criteria of rationality, even while a computer may not possess a "mind". But, like I said, this classification depends on definitions.
If we were to strictly require a mind (i.e. consciousness) for something to qualify as rational, this may be a distinction without a difference. If we say "rationality = has consciousness + generates output from input by following laws of logic and reason", then we could separate rationality into those two components, which we might refer to as consciousness and proxy-rationality respectively, in which case what I said above and below could apply to proxy-rationality. Given the existence of computers, having consciousness doesn't seem to be required for proxy-rationality, and it's questionable whether the unintelligibility of Being then necessarily follow, despite having the capacity for proxy-rationality (although I also reject that inference for other reasons, as below).

For premise 4, if we're talking about a disjunction that can either be exclusive or inclusive, then I'm not sure how that inference follows. If there's a potential overlap between being and rationality, then you don't seem to get to it being the case that Being is inherently irrational. It seems that disjunction would need to be exclusive for that to follow. Otherwise we've just concluded that there may be some things that are rational, and there may be some things that aren't.
Also, you seem to be conflating rationality with intelligibility. Something could be said to be intelligible if it follows patterns. Meanwhile, rationality would be about the ability to identify those patterns. So even if there were a "disjunction between being and rationality" (which I don't accept), this still doesn't lead to the implication that being is unintelligible and that we can't model being.
I'll also note the distinction made above between rationality and proxy-rationality (i.e. rationality without consciousness). If we're saying something needs to be conscious for it to be intelligible, that seems like a huge issue. If we say proxy-rationality is sufficient, I've already argued that this can exist without minds, but I'd say it's weaker than this: there just needs to exist patterns for us to be able to recognise them, and the existence of patterns doesn't seem to require even proxy-rationality.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

David Bentley Hart
I have a feeling David Bentley Hart will be agreeable to you.
Note: The book seems to be written by a traditional Christian theologian but from the very subtitle itself — Being Consciousness Bliss — he goes beyond traditional Christianity integrating Vedantic ideas with classical Christians like Anselm.

By philosophical atheism I mean some version of materialism or physicalism or (to use the term most widely preferred at present) naturalism; and naturalism — the doctrine that there is nothing apart from the physical order, and certainly nothing supernatural — is an incorrigibly incoherent concept, and one that is ultimately indistinguishable from pure magical thinking.

[Because...]

The very notion of nature as a closed system entirely sufficient to itself is plainly one that cannot be verified, deductively or empirically, from within the system of nature. It is a metaphysical (which is to say “extra-natural”) conclusion regarding the whole of reality, which neither reason nor experience legitimately warrants. It cannot even define itself within the boundaries of its own terms, because the total sufficiency of “natural” explanations is not an identifiable natural phenomenon but only an arbitrary judgment. Naturalism, therefore, can never be anything more than a guiding prejudice...
In other words: philosophical atheism-as-naturalism cannot provide a warrant for its worldview.

Note: You just need to map his "metaphysical", "extra-natural" to your "categorical".
Georg Lukács
Another somewhat unlikely thinker you may glance over is Georg Lukács

When we look at the relations which can exist between being and consciousness we see clearly that only two positions are possible: either being is primary (materialism), or consciousness is primary (idealism). Or, to put it another way, the fundamental principle of materialism is the independence of being from consciousness; of idealism, the dependence of being on consciousness.


I like David Bentley Hart. He's a very good thinker.

@Sismetic Added a para on Lukacs

I find it kinda funny (and rather intellectually dishonest) when people say the rejection of unverifiable things is unverifiable incoherent magical thinking... so that they can sneak in their own unverifiable incoherent conclusions based on magical thinking. It's truly a sad time when people try to argue that "only accept things as true if you have good reason to" is a poor epistemology (that tends to be the guiding principle behind naturalism). Their "best" / typical attempt to argue against that involves them strawmanning the hell out of it (like Hart does).

@NotThatGuy I find it kinda funny that you say you find it kinda funny when you most clearly are more annoyed than amused

@Rushi Something being "kinda funny" doesn't preclude it from being annoying, and someone being annoyed doesn't preclude them from being right.

@NotThatGuy Touché! U win this round. But beware! We (non materialists) will win the last round since winning-losing does not exist in your atoms-bouncing-around universe

"You can't win. You can't break even. You can't even quit the game."


Being is such a general term that you hardly find any ontological entity which does not deal with being (= existent)
things.

Physicalism (taken as a neutral word better better than the fighting
concept “materialism”) does not separate "Being" and "Mentality"
because the two concepts cannot be separated and cannot be played
out one against the other. Hence to invoke ”Being” is not relevant
for discussing the pro and cons of physicalism .

Mental processes are dynamic events. They cannot be captured with
the traditional concept “substance”. One needs the concept of a
“process” to discuss mental processes. And these neuronal processes
are appropriately investigated by neuroscience.
The concept of information is much more suited to investigate mental processes than concepts from physics alone. Considering mental processes from the viewpoint of information processing shows the path: How to give up the barren quarreling with pretentious traditional concepts and to develop a scientific approach to the problem of the mind.



One reasonable counter argument is that that's potentially the opposite of the truth, Materialism is a type of monism, which means all of it is wrapped up in this place we call the physical world.

I'm sorry, I am not sure what the counter here is.  I understand materialism is monist(in fact, I have an argument about how even property dualists require a monism of substance to be called materialists), and that this requires to be a total move(all real entities are substantially matter).
But this is something I already assume, which seems a base axiom of materialism, so not sure how this refutes or engages with my argument. Am I missing something? Your answer seems very brief.

@Sismetic the argument proposed in op against materialism is that they're separate - my argument above is that this means they're not separate at all.

I think this point is addressed on 3. It's not a separation but a conceptual distinction. "Matter" and "Mind" are distinct categories. I understand emergent ontologies would explain this as "Mind" being a posterior movement, and so there's no SEPARATION,  because all thinking matter is matter, but the point is that matter is not inherently mental or thinking and hence there is a conceptual distinction.
That is why no the 3.2, I added the notion of inclusive disjunction(distinction) as opposed to what you seem to be thinking of exclusive disjunction(separation)


X is a body iff X exists and X is divisible.

X is a point particle iff X exists and X isn't divisible.


Therefore, by the propositional calculus
X is a point particle or X is a body iff X exists.
Therefore, if X exists then X is matter.
Therefore only matter exists.
There is nothing inconsistent with this.
Materialism is the doctrine that only matter exists.
Therefore there is nothing inconsistent with materialism.
To exist means to be in the current moment in time.
Concepts, ideas, thoughts, aren't in the current moment in time, therefore they don't exist.
A definition is a concept, and as such does not exist.
Ontology is the science of 'Being', but philosophers fail to define 'Being'.  Materialists, on the other hand define what it means to exist.
Therefore, the position of materialism is not incoherent.

I think this fails to answer to the argument.
Beyond issues with the argument you presented, it seems a reproduction of the issue: you are providing ideal categories, concepts, semantic statements, logical relations to produce a schematic net of meaning which then you seem to be projecting as accurate corresponding to reality, hence requiring Matter/Being to inherently be mental in Nature(at least partially).
Given that your answer is conceptual, and this would not tie to Matter, your task is impossible: describe and explain and justify materialism without appealing to mentality

There is nothing inconsistent with this. Not inconsistent but circular. Your "exists" = "Physically exists".

@Rushi
My point is largely is that "consistency" is an ideal category, it's not a material category. There can't be a material category for categoriality is antithetical to materiality. That is why materialism is a contradiction: to posit itself and to ground its meaning and reality, it requires essentially ideal categories which would not apply to the material substance essentially, inherently or conceptually.

U don't need to argue with me @Sismetic. To me it's all baloney

#sismetic, the weak point in your argument is that you have failed to provide a clear definition of 'mentality'.  I think it would help if you edit your post by providing a definition of 'mentality'.  I sort of know what you mean, but to show you your error I need a logical definition of 'mentality'.

A complete definition mentality seems like a hard task. I don't that complete definitions are possible or necessary, especially in certain primitive notions, and I think that a partial one is sufficient for it seems you understand it. But in fairness, I'll try to give the clearest definition of mentality:
By mentality I mean all qualities and properties essential and distinctive of the mind. It includes aspects like judgement, thought, consciousness, perception, relationality, intentionality, and so on.
Does this satisfy and is it sufficient for understanding the argument?

the weak point in your argument is that you have failed to provide a clear definition of 'mentality' Again a (meta-)circularity. When you say "definition" you mean "phyiscalist's definition". @Sistemic is questioning physicalism and you are assuming physicalism to prove physicalism. For the idealist mentality is a primary primitive just as for the physicalist (materialist), matter is a primary primitive

@Rushi, I am surrounded by matter, I am not surrounded by ideas.  There's a big difference between an idealist and a materialist.  I am not assuming only matter exists.  I know it, and no one can know that which is false.  Communicating what I know to another piece of matter requires symbols.  I organized my symbols logically, that's the best a perfect being can do.  I'm not implying I'm perfect, I'm just saying....

Thats odd! Are you thus surrounded? I thought you asked intelligent questions. Is that intelligence matter? Do you experience it so? Note: You brought up experience by saying we're surrounded by matter — thats your experience. If you say so I must respect your saying. But it's not remotely my experience. (1/3)

Leave aside matter which is really an extremal abatraction, I am not even surrounded by wood, plastic, metal. But by this chair, this spoon i eat with, this device in my hand. When you start to grok that even wood, plastic, metal are absteact categories that are questionable in corner cases, you can begin to appreciate that the abstraction of abstractions, matter, is really a wild abstraction, more wild than universe, certainly more wild than God. (2/3)

Ramanujan saw himself surrounded by numbers. It's not a common experience for us less mathematically endowed mortals. But it certainly was his. To be surrounded by dead matter is amongst the most dismal possible ways of viewing the world.  Why make that your truth? (3/3)
